# Run ASP.NET MVC in Internet Hosting Providers

Tags: asp.net-mvc, hosting

My question is very simple. Can I run an [ASP.NET MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC_Framework) application on shared servers that has installed ASP.NET 3.5 but not MVC?

If this is possible could you tell me how?

Answer (score 3):

You just need to include `System.Web.dll` in the bin folder and it should work fine (and maybe in the dll folder for routing. I'll check out for exact article for this in a moment).

---

[Here's](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/03/bin-deploy-aspnetmvc.aspx) a link with proper a TODO.

Most interesting part:

> With the release of ASP.NET MVC Beta, the assemblies distributed with ASP.NET MVC are automatically installed into the GAC.
>   System.Web.Mvc
>   System.Web.Routing
>   System.Web.Abstractions
>
> While developing an application locally, this isn’t a problem. But when you are ready to deploy your application to a hosting provider, this might well be a problem if the hoster does not have the ASP.NET MVC assemblies installed in the GAC.
>
> Fortunately, ASP.NET MVC is still bin-deployable. If your hosting provider has ASP.NET 3.5 SP1 installed, then you’ll only need to include the MVC DLL. If your hosting provider is still on ASP.NET 3.5, then you’ll need to deploy all three. It turns out that it’s really easy to do so.

Comment: One problem I foresee could be the routing. If the servers are running IIS6, you need to do that workaround to get the ISAPI filters to interpret page requests properly. It's unlikely that is something a shared hosting provider will accommodate.