# How can I get a fusion binding log on a host that does not have it enabled?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to run an Asp.net MVC 1 app on a host that doesn't support MVC per [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1715700/run-asp-net-mvc-in-internet-hosting-providers) post but does support .net 2,3,3.5

However the error message I get back doesn't tell me much:

```
Server Error in '/assetmanagement' Application.
Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'TryHTTPHandler' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error:

[No relevant source lines]


Source File: D:\Hosting\4582955\html\web.config    Line: 65

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'TryHTTPHandler' could not be loaded.

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:2.0.50727.3603; ASP.NET Version:2.0.50727.4049
```

A google search or stack overflow search for TryHTTPHandler seems to turn up almost nothing.

line 65 of my `web.config` is as follows:

```
<add name="AspNetSqlProfileProvider" type="System.Web.Profile.SqlProfileProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ApplicationServices" applicationName="/"/>
```

I've turned on copy local for System.Web, System.Web.Mvc, System.Web.Routing, and System.Web.Abstractions. I'm not sure how to determine if my host has .net 3.5 or .net 3.5 SP1.

How can I get the binding log or any other idea what's wrong with my configuration? I'm fairly limited on what I can do on the host since it's paid hosting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the error message closely, it tells you how to enable the fusion log:  Since you don't have access to the host registry you'll have to try to reproduce the issue on a machine you do control

```
WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

Comment: so short of having to configure a machine or virtual machine to the known parameters and hoping it's not one of the unknown configuration parameters, any idea what else I might try?